# Is there a method to parameterise any surface? And how could I parametrise this one given?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric

I'm having major trouble every time I need to parametrise a surface in order to take a surface integral, I just have no idea where to even start half of the time. Is there some kind of method that can be used or is it just about thinking how we should best define the surface?

Example of one I'm trying to parametrise.

$$x^2+y^2-2x+z^2=0$$

How could I do this one, I was thinking I should complete the square in $x$ then say rearrange to get $z=f(x,y)$ then say $x=\alpha, y=\beta$ then $z=f(\alpha,\beta)$ would be a parametrisation but according to the solution there are trigonometric functions involved and angles etc. And I just don't see where they come from and the solution doesn't explain it at all.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
x^2+y^2-2x+z^2=0\Longrightarrow (x-1)^2 + y^2+z^2=1.
$$
We know that
$$
\cos^2 a + \sin^2 a = 1.
$$
Let's use it! Denote
$$
(x-1)^2 + y^2 = \sin^2\theta,\\
z=\cos\theta
$$
Rewrite first:
$$
(x-1)^2 + y^2 = \sin^2\theta\Longrightarrow \frac{(x-1)^2}{\sin^2\theta}+\frac{y^2}{\sin^2\theta}=1,
$$
and use previous trick again:
$$
x-1=\sin\theta\cos\phi,\\
y=\sin\theta\sin\phi.
$$

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand why this would be a parameterisation and how you would even think to use it. I don't even know what $\theta$ and $\phi$ are.

Comment: $\theta$ and $\phi$ are just a parameters. But they have geometric meaning. Do you familiar with spherical coordinates?

Comment: Kind of. Are they they same as the angles in spherical co-ordinates then?

Comment: Yep. Roughly speaking, spherical coordinates parametrizes a sphere. And  its are more elegant way (in some sense) than square roots